# Javascript, find nested property if exists

Tags: javascript, lodash

Folks,
  Given an object, I just need to find and return the first `tag` property nested in something like:

```
{
   data: { 
     cat: false,
     horse: { 
        tag: 'somestring' 
     },
     dog: false
   }       
}
```

*note*: data can also be false.

What would be the simplest method to use using lodash?  Can probably look decent using a recursive function... Can probably hack something up natively, but I am certain kind folks have shorter, easier to read way

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "first" as keys in an object have no order.

Comment: find the first tag and return it.  thats all I meant.  Order is irrelevant in my case, tag can be anywhere in the object.

Comment: Can `tag` appear anywhere or only at the position shown in your example?

Comment: tag is always 2 levels deep under car/horse/dog, nowhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned tag will be present in any of "CAT/DOG/HORSE". Why not use simple ternary operator

```
myObj.data.cat ? myObj.data.cat.tag : (myObj.data.horse ? myObj.data.horse.tag : (myObj.data.dog ? myObj.data.dog.tag : false));
```

Answer (score 1):

This iterate function will return first tag key value.

```
function iterate (obj, key) {
var result;

for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // in case it is an object
        if (typeof obj[property] === "object") {
            result = iterate(obj[property], key);

            if (typeof result !== "undefined") {
                return result;
            }
        }
        else if (property === key) {
            return obj[key]; // returns the value
        }
    }   
  }
}
```

pass your object and key in function. `iterate(obj,'tag');`

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want an easier way, (not the best performance) and easy to manipulate the code then you can pass a callback to `JSON.parse` (what we use to control the parsing) and check for key in the stringified version of the object.

Let's create a simple example and we will make that a liitle efficient to break it while first match is found.

Here is the simple one

```js
var obj = {
   data: { 
     cat: false,
     horse: { 
        tag: 'somestring' 
     },
     dog: false
   }       
}
function keyExist(object, key) {
    var flag = false;
    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object), function(k, v) {
 if(k===key) {flag=true};
     return v;
    });
    return flag;
};

console.log('Key [tag]: ' + keyExist(obj, "tag"));
console.log('Key [dog]: ' + keyExist(obj, "dog"));
console.log('Key [rat]: ' + keyExist(obj, "rat"));
```

Now, lets throw an error when we found it, handle that and return true, otherwise return false

```js
var obj = {
   data: { 
     cat: false,
     horse: { 
        tag: 'somestring' 
     },
     dog: false
   }       
}
function keyExist(object, key) {
    try {
     JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object), function(k, v) {
     if(k===key) {throw v};
            return v;
     });
    } catch(e) {return true};
    return false;
};

console.log('Key [tag]: ' + keyExist(obj, "tag"));
console.log('Key [dog]: ' + keyExist(obj, "dog"));
console.log('Key [rat]: ' + keyExist(obj, "rat"));
```

However you have the value in both the case, in variable `v` for the first case and in variable `e` while catching in the second case, if you want that value you can return that.

But remember easier doesn't always meant faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash's [`_.some()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some) recursively to find a nested property value:

```js
var obj = {
   data: { 
     cat: false,
     horse: { 
        tag: 'somestring' 
     },
     dog: false
   }       
};

function findProp(obj, prop) {
  var propValue; // the value that we'll return - undefined if prop wasn't found
  
  function iterate(obj) {
    // _.some can iterate arrays and objects, and will break immediately when true is returned
    return _.some(obj, function(value, key) {
      if(key === prop) { 
        propValue = value; // update the propValue
        return true; // return true to finish the loop
      }
      
      // if the prop value is an object or an array iterate it or return false
      return _.isObject(value) ? iterate(value) : false;
    });
  }
  
  iterate(obj);
  
  return propValue;
}

var result = findProp(obj, 'tag');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching being clever and solved it in a quick loop:

```
//lodash
let tag = false;
_.each(data, function (thing) {
   if (_.has(thing, 'tag')) {
      tag = thing.tag;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of you additional input that data can be two level deep with the path `data > horse > tag` (or whatever else the path is) why don't you simply use **lodash's** `_.get` function with the path??

eg

`_.get(obj, 'data.horse.cat') !== undefined` (assuming you may have false value but not undefined)

or if you have the possibility of undefined value then

`'tag' in (_.get(obj, 'data.horse') || {})`

Here is an working snippet:

```js
var obj = {
   data: { 
     cat: false,
     horse: { 
        tag: 'somestring' 
     },
     dog: false
   }       
}

console.log('tag: ' +  _.get(obj, 'data.horse.tag') )

// or if you just want to check the existance
// considering it can contain undefined value as well

console.log('tag: ' + ('tag' in _.get(obj, 'data.horse') || {}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```